# If $a+S \in \mathbb{Q} / S$ is nonzero, where $a \in \mathbb{Q}$ then there is $b \in \mathbb{Q}$ with $a=p b$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

[Rotman, Advanced Modern Algebra, Third Edition, Part 1]:

> **Theorem B-2.3.** If $R$ is a nonzero commutative ring, then $R$ has a maximal ideal. Indeed, every proper ideal $U$ in $R$ is contained in a maximal ideal.
>
> **Remark**.
>
> (ii) Theorem B-2.3 would be false if the definition of ring $R$ did not insist on $R$ containing 1. An example of such a "ring without unit" is any additive abelian group $G$ with multiplication defined by $a b=0$ for all $a, b \in G$ The usual definition of ideal makes sense, and it is easy to see that a subset $S \subseteq G$ is an ideal if and only if it is a subgroup. Thus, a maximal ideal $S$ is just a maximal subgroup; that is, $G / S$ has no proper subgroups, which says that $G / S$ is a simple abelian group. But an abelian group is simple if and only if it is a finite group of prime order, so that $S$ is a maximal ideal in $G$ if and only if $|G / S|=p$ for some prime $p$.
>
> Now choose $G=\mathbb{Q}$, the additive abelian group of all rationals, and suppose $S \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$ is a maximal subgroup with $|\mathbb{Q} / S|=p$; by Lagrange's Theorem, $p(\mathbb{Q} / S)=\{0\}$. **But if $a+S \in \mathbb{Q} / S$ is nonzero, where $a \in \mathbb{Q}$ then there is $b \in \mathbb{Q}$ with $a=p b$.** Hence, $0 \neq a+S=p b+S \in p(\mathbb{Q} / S)=$ $\{0\}$, a contradiction. Thus, $\mathbb{Q}$ has no maximal subgroups and, therefore, the "ring without unit" $\mathbb{Q}$ has no maximal ideals.

I don't understand this sentence: But if $a+S \in \mathbb{Q} / S$ is nonzero, where $a \in \mathbb{Q}$ then there is $b \in \mathbb{Q}$ with $a=p b$.

Why does this $b$ exist?

Thank you.

Comment: $b = \frac{a}{p}$ is a rational number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ingredients in the counterexample. I'll write groups with the additive notation.

**Proposition.** *An infinite abelian group $G$ is not simple.*
*Proof.* If $G$ has an element $g\ne0$ having finite order, then $\{0\}\ne\langle g\rangle\ne G$. If every nonzero element has infinite order, then for $g\ne0$ we have $\langle g\rangle\cong\mathbb{Z}$, so it is not simple. QED

**Corollary.** *If $S$ is a maximal subgroup of the abelian group $G$, then $G/S$ is finite.*
*Proof.* $S$ is maximal if and only if $G/S$ is simple. QED

**Proposition.** *The group $\mathbb{Q}$ of rationals has no proper subgroup $S$ such that $\mathbb{Q}/S$ is finite.*
*Proof.* Suppose $S$ is a subgroup such that $\mathbb{Q}/S$ is finite of order $n$. Take $a+S\in\mathbb{Q}/S$ with $a\notin S$; then also $b=a/n\notin S$. On the other hand $n(b+S)=0+S$, because the quotient group has order $n$. Contradiction. QED

Putting together these facts, we conclude that $\mathbb{Q}$ has no maximal subgroup.

What do I mean by $a/n$? Since $a\in\mathbb{Q}$ we can write $a=x/y$ with $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$. Hence
$$
b=\frac{x}{ny}
$$
satisfies $nb=a$ and can be denoted as $a/n$, because it is the unique rational number with this property.